# Eclipse - using common environmental variables

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables

So, I am having a project which I am required to update an environmental variable of the testing execution due to external reasons. In parallel, I am executing the tests in different ways (unittesting, performance, specific module...), so that I need to change the environmental variables of all these configurations everytime I am externally requesting, creating some administrative work.

Is there any way to set up a common environmental variable for different test configurations?

Looking to eclipse [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm) I do not see any way to perform it, so I am really looking for a hack (maybe modifying configuration file programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own Variables in Preferences > Run/Debug > String substitution. Then you can use those variables in "Environment" settings of your Run/Debug configuration.